# Using `syscall.LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_POWER_OFF` when programming on windows for linux

Tags: linux, windows, go, raspberry-pi

I'm developing code using Golang on windows as it is easier for testing purposes, but the final bin should run on a raspberry pi.

I need to call `syscall.Reboot(syscall.LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_POWER_OFF)` which works fine however, I need to comment it out on windows to test the binary and uncomment it when building in on the rpi.
Even if I test the os to determine if the function is called, since it does not seem to exist on windows, go won't build it.
Is there a way to build the code on windows even though this function doesn't exist?

I do not wish to do any code edits on the rpi, and i cannot use the wsl i need to communicate with usb devices and such which is easier when building on the native os

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want conditional compilation as described here:

https://blog.ralch.com/articles/golang-conditional-compilation/

You could have two source files in your package that use the `_os` nomenclature as the name. Both files export a function that does the appropriate behavior.

**reboot_linux.go**

```
package main

import "syscall"

func Reboot() {
    syscall.Reboot(syscall.LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_POWER_OFF)
}
```

**reboot_windows.go**

```
package main

import "fmt"

func Reboot() {
    fmt.Println("A reboot would have occurred")
}
```

When you do `go build` it won't compile `reboot_linux.go` on Windows. Nor will it compile `reboot_windows.go` on Linux.

Interestingly enough - this is exactly how Go separates out the implementations of the syscall package in its own source code.

Comment: This looks promising, but I might be using the wrong build command as i call all files `go build -o bin/main src/*.go` hence I get this output ```
# command-line-arguments
src\systemcalls_windows.go:5:6: Reboot redeclared in this block
        src\systemcalls_linux.go:5:6: other declaration of Reboot
src\systemcalls_windows.go:10:6: Shutdown redeclared in this block
        src\systemcalls_linux.go:9:6: other declaration of Shutdown
...```

Comment: Just change your build command to be `go build -o bin/main src/.`